# PHP returns the resultset of query by primary key

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I am trying to fetch the first X rows from a database by their publication date in descending order, however I found that while the query works perfectly well if executed directly on my local database, in PHP the resultset is always in the order of the primary keys.
Here is the piece of code:

```
public static function getList( $numRows=1000000, $order="publicationDate DESC" ) {
$conn = new PDO( db_host, db_user, db_pw );
$sql = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(publicationDate) AS publicationDate FROM blogs
        ORDER BY " . ":order" . " LIMIT :numRows";

$st = $conn->prepare( $sql );
$st->bindValue( ":numRows", $numRows, PDO::PARAM_INT );
$st->bindValue( ":order", $order, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$st->execute();
$list = array();

while ( $row = $st->fetch() ) {
  echo $row['id'];
  $article = new Blogpost( $row );
  $list[] = $article;
}


// Now get the total number of articles that matched the criteria
$sql = "SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS totalRows";
$totalRows = $conn->query( $sql )->fetch();
$conn = null;
return ( array ( "results" => $list, "totalRows" => $totalRows[0] ) );
}
```

When this runs, the output from the echos is as follows: 
50 51 52 53 54

The database was created using this query (to show you structure):

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS blogs;
 CREATE TABLE blogs
(
  id              smallint unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  publicationDate date NOT NULL,
  title           varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  summary         text NOT NULL,
  content         mediumtext NOT NULL,
  views           int(11) NOT NULL,
  previewPic      varchar(255) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY     (id)
);
```

I've tried running different queries and it is always returned in ascending order of the primary key. Why?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot parameterize identifiers, such as column names, table names, functions, and operators.

Say you think you are ordering by:

```
order by views
```

In actuality, this is:

```
order by 'views'  -- a constant string
```

I am guessing that MySQL is smart enough to know that ordering by a string is useless, so it returns it in the order the data is read.  Note:  it is not guaranteed that this will be primary key order, although that is often the case.

Unfortunately, you will have to mangle the query string, so you can generate:

```
order by views  -- or whatever column you want
```

Comment: What do you mean by mangling the query string? publicationDate is a date datatype (in fact, unix timestamp) so it shouldn't have an issue

Comment: @peterxz  . . .  Putting extra strings into the query string.  It would be nice if everything could be put in as a parameter (which you are doing).  Alas, that is not possible for this case.

Comment: Ah I get what you mean. Thanks. I solved it by taking it out of the parameter and directly putting it into the query. But if i want to be able to switch between ascending and desceding, is there any way? Or should I pre-write both queries and decide using an if block?

Comment: Use two different `order by` clauses (you can then append them to the same base query).  You *could* do something like `order by (case when ? = 'ASC' then X end) asc, X desc`, but I think constructing the `order by` clause is simpler.